# Get access token from Azure AD using Password grant for Automation Testing

Tags: oauth-2.0, automated-tests, azure-active-directory

I have a Function App hosted in Azure that uses AAD for authentication with approles defined in the app registration. The users are created in on-prem AD and synced to Azure AD. Then they are assigned specific roles on the Function App. Depending on the role, the user can access certain functions. All works well.

Now in automation tests for this Function App, I wanted access token for couple of test user accounts so the tests can run in context of the user. I tried getting token using Password grant however I am getting invalid_grant error that reads "AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password". After some research I came across [joonasw](https://joonasw.net/view/ropc-grant-flow-in-azure-ad) blog which says ROPC does not work with Users synced with on-prem AD.

Is there any documentation from Microsoft confirming this? Or is there any other alternative to get the access tokens given the test code can provide test user account password

Comment: Do you _require_ your test users to be synced from on-premises?

Comment: There are some restriction for that code flow you could check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Yes, all our AD users including service accounts are created on-prem and synced to Azure AD. So no option there to use cloud only AD users :(

Comment: Do you _have_ to test on your production tenant?